# FSCalendar multiple Selection customization

Tags: ios, fscalendar

I am using FSCalendar to implement a custom calendar. I managed to make something similar to the following by changing a few methods and handling the various select and deselect modes.

Here is a screenshot of what I have so far:

[image]

Now the designer wants a different color for all the dates lying between the initial and final date. Example: Apart from 13th March and 22nd March in the screenshot, all the dates should be a different color.

How do I go about changing the color of the dates inside the range excluding the final and initial values?

**Or**

If someone could suggest another project/pod that will create a similar UI to the screenshot above and satisfy the color requirements, that also works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone wants to know how i went around doing this, I had to setup new `BOOL` properties inside each cell, to keep track of wether the cell is the first, last or lies within the range. And then call the `configureCell` function provided in the pod and setup different colors based on the `BOOL` values at appropriate places. Inside the `FSCalendarCell` `configureAppearance`:

```
if (self.isCellInsideDateRange){

    cellFillColor = [self colorFromHexString:mainDictionary[@"calendarLightColor"]].CGColor;

}else if(self.isCellFirstCell || self.isCellLastCell){

    cellFillColor = [self colorFromHexString:mainDictionary[@"calendarDarkColor"]].CGColor;

}else{

    cellFillColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
}
```

And inside `FSCalendar.m` inside each `cellForItemAtIndexPath` check wether the date inside the cell lies within the range of selected dates and set the appropriate `BOOL` values to `true` or `false`

I'll admit it required quite **a lot of** handling on my part and even then i wasn't able to resolve some crashes that started occurring due to cell re-use and it being unable to deque re-usable cells. Most probably caused by the combination of handling i had to do to handle various app specific cases, adding new properties and the time the cell color animations take to appear.

In the end i used the JTAppleCalendar that offers quite a lot of customization albeit no animation but its a small thing when compared to the customization capabilities.

Comment: can you mind sharing the full code?